# Prove $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^n}$ converges uniformly on $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am not sure that this correct, please give some feedback and help.
Real analysis: the sequence of functions

Prove $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^n}$ converges uniformly on $(0,1)$

[image]

Comment: No personal input + Wrong result = ?

Comment: Correct result, just in the image.

Comment: Please type it. Don't give us the handwritten proofs.

Comment: @Ingix Yeah, which is kind of the problem with this question.

Comment: Your homework asked you to prove that it is uniformly convergent?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correct and prove that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to the limit $f=1$.

As you can see from the remarks on your question, people vastly prefer that formulas are given with MathJax instead of a photo of hand written notices. This has the advantage that it can be scaled as necessary by any viewer, and is generally very easy to read (your notes are very legible, but that is not true for every contributor). Find a [tutorial here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which covers 95% of things I need.